# How to make custom cursor image not disappear

Tags: css

```
div {
    cursor:url(smiley.gif),url(myBall.cur),auto;
}
```

It seems that whenever you specific a custom image in the cursor property, the image only appears for a moment and then revers to the default.

You can watch this behavior here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_cursor&preval=url(smiley.gif),url(myBall.cur),auto

I get the same result in Chrome and Firefox. Is there a way to make the image remain?

Comment: The link you give works fine for me (smiley). I'm using Vivaldi, which is based on Chrome. If I test in Edge, I don't get the smiley gif, but the ball cursor, but again, it remains there.

Comment: No flicker here (latest Chrome)

Comment: No flicker on Chrome for macOS

Comment: No flicker Safari Mac

Comment: Maybe try without the second (`.cur`) one? https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/3mhefu54/

Comment: @KevinJantzer For me it takes longer on Chrome, but if you leave the cursor in the box for 3-4 seconds it disappears. Is that now what happens for you?

Comment: @j08691 ^ same question

Comment: I wonder if my question title was unclear. The problem isn't that the image flickers when it appears. Rather, if I leave the mouse hovering over the box for a few seconds it disappears and returns to the default arrow

Comment: @emersonthis – Nope, left my cursor umoved in the box for 10+ seconds and it was fine. Tested on both Chrome 51.0.2704.103 and 52.0.2743.116.
Have you tried testing it in incognito mode to see if a Chrome extension is causing it?

Comment: it does have to do with overflow. if i change the `x y` positioning, it effects when the cursor reverts. notably, chrome is deprecating custom cursors that are bigger than 32x32 DPI and the problem goes away if you set the size to 32x32

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is caused by other elements who do not inherit the custom cursor or their cursor is overridden by other CSS.

Consider the following basic example:

```css
div {
    cursor: url("http://placehold.it/50x50"), auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius, saepe.</p>
  <p>Quis doloremque, reiciendis minima veniam natus id repudiandae vitae quod?</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis, corporis.</p>
  <p>Odit, suscipit atque quae nihil quos asperiores enim fugiat iusto.</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores, a!</p>
  <p>Vel reprehenderit, blanditiis sunt numquam cum iste incidunt veniam sint.</p>
</div>
```

When you move the mouse around, it will alternate between the custom cursor and the default one, because the cursor is applied to `div`s only and when you move mouse to other element, it might "flicker".

In this case, it's best to wrap everything inside a general container OR apply custom cursor to the `body`/`html` tag:

```css
html {
    cursor: url("http://placehold.it/50x50"), auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius, saepe.</p>
  <p>Quis doloremque, reiciendis minima veniam natus id repudiandae vitae quod?</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis, corporis.</p>
  <p>Odit, suscipit atque quae nihil quos asperiores enim fugiat iusto.</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores, a!</p>
  <p>Vel reprehenderit, blanditiis sunt numquam cum iste incidunt veniam sint.</p>
</div>
```

But again, you have to make sure it does not get overridden by any other rules.

Comment: Interesting. Do you know what the expected behavior is when `cursor` is applied to nested elements? Do the inner nodes not inherit the property from the outer? Like `color`?

Comment: Inner nodes are expected to inherit parent's cursor by default. Unless another rule CSS manipulates the cursor for certain elements (check entire CSS file(s) for `cursor` property). Alternatively, a JavaScript code might be overriding the cursor property. You can also apply `cursor: inherit` to child elements.

Answer (score 0):

This is a better idea because you can take element that you prefer to change your cursor inside .

```
[your-element] {
    cursor: url("http://placehold.it/50x50"), auto!important;
}
```

Adding !important solve the problem of overiding your code by custom styles .