# CSS - Custom cursor image is reverting near edges of the viewport in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have a page where the entire area is covered by a link. I have implemented a custom cursor with a [60x60 px PNG image](https://i.ibb.co/pRX8Fxg/close.png) when the user hovers over the link (so anywhere on the page, the cursor should appear as a white X).

My issue is this: When the cursor (or rather, the edge of the image shown by the cursor) touches the edge of the page, the cursor reverts to the "pointer" state which I assigned as a fallback. Here's the CSS I used:

```
cursor: url('https://i.ibb.co/pRX8Fxg/close.png') 30 30, pointer;
```

In the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/varspw19/) I made of the issue, this only seems to happen with the top and left sides, and not the bottom and right sides (which is very confusing since that invalidates my theory that it was due to the edge of the browser). In my page however this happens with all four sides.

The issue is nonexistent with Firefox, and with Edge when I use a .cur file.

I've tried: using a .cur file instead, changing the position of the hotspot, trying to figure out what jsfiddle's page does differently.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe the answer here helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38906002/how-to-make-custom-cursor-image-not-disappear

Comment: Having the same issue, did you find a solution? Seems to me that it is when the cursor image overflows the browser viewport at the edges of the browser - nothing to do with what element is underneath. Works fine in Safari, but happens for me in Edge, Firefox and Chrome on Mac.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm reproducing it the same way, but for some reason I'm only able to reproduce when setting my Chrome network to "Slow 3G". When I switch it back to "Online" the cursor is only momentarily set to the fallback but quickly changes to the image.

Answer (score 12):

Keep your cursor smaller or equal to 32x32 DIP.

> Custom cursors with widths or heights greater than 32 DIP will be
> removed if they intersect native UX (i.e. are not fully contained in
> the visual viewport).
>
> Large cursors are being used abusively on the web, to confuse users
> (see https://crbug.com/880863). Specifically, large custom cursors can
> be used to cover important (sometimes security related) browser native
> UX with an arbitrary image to mislead users into thinking they are
> clicking outside the content area.

Source: https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5825971391299584