# Avoid custom cursor to disappear when reaching border of window

Tags: css, cursor

I'm having a custom cursor (an svg arrow) in my page.
The problem comes when I reach the border of the browser/window with the limit of the image; it disappears and turns into a default cursor pointer.

Is there a way I can avoid the cursor to break/disappear when doing that?

Thanks

Comment: Could you share how you implemented your custom cursor so we can see how your code looks and what conditions could change the behavior?

Comment: .swiper-button-next {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
cursor: url("images/image.svg"), default;
}

Answer (score 2):

Please be sure your custom cursor is not greater than 32x32 px.
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/65032905